# Why I get this error trying to set page title?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

The official documentation tells to use `title` property of `Route` to set page title. https://angular.io/guide/router#setting-the-page-title

> Each page in your application should have a unique title so that they can be identified in the browser history. The Router sets the document's title using the title property from the Route config.

But I get this error:

> Type '{ path: string; title: string; component: typeof
> SecondComponent; }' is not assignable to type 'Route'.   Object
> literal may only specify known properties, and 'title' does not exist
> in type 'Route'.

```
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { SingleComponent } from './single/single.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FirstComponent } from './first/first.component';
import { SecondComponent } from './second/second.component';
import { ChildAComponent } from './child-a/child-a.component';
import { ChildBComponent } from './child-b/child-b.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'first', component: FirstComponent, children: [
      { path: 'child-a', component: ChildAComponent },
      { path: 'child-b', component: ChildBComponent },
  ]},
  { path: 'second', title: 'Second page title', component: SecondComponent }, // here an error
  { path: 'single', component: SingleComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/first', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use the Angular 14's route API, which is only in beta actually :)

Under version 14, if you want to set page title, you must use `data` property and set a property "title", such as :

```
{
   path: 'tralala',
   component: TralalaComponent,
   data: {
      title: 'My Title'
   }
}
```

Then, in your page component (TralalaComponent), inject the Angular's [TitleService](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Title) and the [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) in order to retrieve the `data` object, get your title and set it.

```
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
....

@Component({......})
export class TralalaComponent implement OnInit {
    constructor(
        private readonly route: ActivatedRoute,
        private readonly titleService: Title
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.titleService.setTitle(this.route.snapshot.data['title'])
    }
}
```

EDIT : Now that Angular 14 is released, you can use the new [`title`](https://angular.io/api/router/Route#title) property in a `Route` object.

Answer (score 3):

Title is not recognized property in Angular 13. See the [API reference here](https://angular.io/api/router/Route). But it is in [Angular 14](https://rc.angular.io/api/router/Route). So your code will work on Angular 14 but not in 13